# Groovy Script to Parse XML values

Tags: xml, parsing, groovy

#### Question

I need a groovy script to parse these ticket names and save them in user attributes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <FTP FTPName="ftp.com.samplecompany.net" Login="CertUser" Pass="Password"></FTP>
  <Ticket name="Accept">
  </Ticket>
  <Ticket name="Afp">    
  </Ticket>
  <Ticket name="Exe">    
  </Ticket>
</root>
```

#### Current Code

```
def tickets = job.getDocuments()[0].getText().split(""></Ticket><Ticket name="") 
def len = tickets.size()
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: def tickets = job.getDocuments()[0].getText().split(""></Ticket><Ticket name="")

def len = tickets.size()

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70063504/edit) the question and add the code there. Comments are not useful to share code. Also what is `job` here - most likely the question needs further tagging. Is this [jenkins]?

Comment: I edited your question per @cfrick recommendations.... granted the does not align with your question.  I posted an answer which should would based off your requirements ( you need to strip the prolog as you will see in my example )

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The following solution will add a new attribute **user** with the same value as **name**

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

def xmlStr = '''
<root>
  <FTP FTPName="ftp.com.samplecompany.net" Login="CertUser" Pass="Password"></FTP>
  <Ticket name="Accept">
  </Ticket>
  <Ticket name="Afp">    
  </Ticket>
  <Ticket name="Exe">    
  </Ticket>
</root>
'''

def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlStr)
xml.Ticket['@name'].eachWithIndex { name, index ->
    xml.Ticket[index].@user = name
}


def outputBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
def updatedXml = outputBuilder.bind{ mkp.yield xml }

println updatedXml
```

If you want to pull the XML to a file then write to the file you can modify the script accordingly

```
def xmlFile = 'file.xml'
def xml = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)

xml.Ticket['@name'].eachWithIndex { name, index ->
    xml.Ticket[index].@user = name
}

new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(xmlFile))).print(xml)
```

This will produce the following file

```
<root>
  <FTP FTPName="ftp.com.samplecompany.net" Login="CertUser" Pass="Password"/>
  <Ticket name="Accept" user="Accept"/>
  <Ticket name="Afp" user="Afp"/>
  <Ticket name="Exe" user="Exe"/>
</root>
```

> **Caution** : It may remove the XML prolog and comments